# Updating href in url redirect htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, dns, hosting

I am trying to show the content of one domain with the url of another. So for example if I go to example1.com I would like to show the content of example2.com without changing the url name.

What I have right now is the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example1.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) example2.com/$1 [P]
```

This works great, but the next step to this that I would like is for internal hrefs of example2.com to remain as example1.com in the url.

So if on the copied page there would be a link to example2.com/about I would like for it to become example1.com/about instead.

Is this possible with htaccess? if not what would be the best way to approach this.

P.S. This is a WordPress site - so if anyone has a good WP specific way of achieving the above that would be fine too.

Thanks in advance!